# Erro ao ler arquivo texto com FileStream C#

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um programa que lê um arquivo da txt da máquina do usuário, todos os outro arquivos são lidos normalmente só um arquivo específico que quando é lido aparece o seguinte erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o erro é no código ou no arquivo em si?

Comment: qual o conteúdo da variável "CaminhoArquivo"?

Comment: o caminho do arquivo que está sendo lido

Comment: E qual o caminho que está sendo lido?

Comment: Eu desconfio que tenha algo a ver com a primeira linha do print, eu comentaria ela e tentaria novamente.